# What have I done wrong in my Maze Navigating program?

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, path-finding, maze

Recently, I was a given a task to create a program that could find the escape route of mazes, stored in .txt files. **My task is to print out both the initial maze and the final maze with the route plotted with '@'.**

[image: Example]

*Where the starting point of the maze is marked as 's', the exit of the maze is marked as 'g', and the walls are marked with '#'.*

Via research, I have tried to create a program based on the Wall Follower algorithm. However, after several tries of debugging, I still could not find what I have done wrong. I have tried my best to label the steps and add additional remarks.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.Write("Please enter the file path of the maze: "); // Prompts the path of the txt.
        string path = Console.ReadLine();
        
        char[,] maze = new char [21,21];
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path)) // Parses the text into the array.
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 21; i++) 
            {
                string line = reader.ReadLine();
                for (int j = 0; j < 21; j++) 
                {
                    maze[i, j] = line[j];
                }
            }
        }
        
        int dir, pos_x, pos_y;
        dir = 0; // (0 = north, 1 = east, 2 = south, 3 = west)
        
        int start_x, start_y; // Marks the start of the maze as the current position.
        start_x = start_y = -1;
        Start(maze, ref start_x, ref start_y);
        pos_x = start_x;
        pos_y = start_y;
        Console.WriteLine("\nThe starting coordinates are:\n{0}, {1}\n\nInitial maze:", pos_x, pos_y);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 21; i++) // Prints out the initial maze.
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 21; j++)
            {
                Console.Write(maze[i, j]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        
        Navigate(maze, dir, pos_x, pos_y); // Start path-finding.
    }
    
    public static void TR(int x, ref int dir) // Turns the player to the right for x times, with the initial direction dir.
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
        {
            dir = (dir + 1) % 4;
        }
    }
    
    public static void MF(int dir, ref int pos_x, ref int pos_y) // Moves forward by 1 grid in the direction of dir.
    {
        switch(dir)
        {
            case 0:
                pos_y++;
                break;
            case 1:
                pos_x++;
                break;
            case 2:
                pos_y--;
                break;
            case 3:
                pos_x--;
                break;
        }
    }
    
    public static bool CheckWall(int dir, int pos_x, int pos_y, char[,] maze) // Checks in the direction of dir, whether there is a wall.
    {
        int x = pos_x;
        int y = pos_y;
        switch(dir)
        {
            case 0:
            y++;
            break;
            case 1:
            x++;
            break;
            case 2:
            y--;
            break;
            case 3:
            x--;
            break;
        }
    
        if (x < 0 || x >= maze.GetLength(0) || y < 0 || y >= maze.GetLength(1))
        {
            return true; // Out of bounds
        }
        else if (maze[x, y] == '#')
        {
            return true; // Wall
        }
        else
        {
            return false; // No wall
        }
    }
    
    public static void Visited(ref char[,] maze, int pos_x, int pos_y) // Marks current blank space into '@'.
    {
        if (maze[pos_x, pos_y] == ' ' || maze[pos_x, pos_y] == 's')
        {
            maze[pos_x, pos_y] = '@';
        }
    }
    
    public static void Start(char[,] maze, ref int x, ref int y) // Marks down the coords of the start.
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 21; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 21; j++)
            {
                if (maze[i, j] == 's')
                {
                    x = i;
                    y = j;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    public static void Navigate(char[,] maze, int dir, int pos_x, int pos_y) // Starts navigating and plotting out the path to the exit.
    {
        Visited(ref maze, pos_x, pos_y);
        TR(1, ref dir);
        while (maze[pos_x, pos_y] != 'g')
        {
            if (CheckWall(dir, pos_x, pos_y, maze) == false)
            {
                TR(1, ref dir);
            }
            else if (CheckWall(dir, pos_x, pos_y, maze) == true)
            {
                TR(3, ref dir);
            }
            MF(dir, ref pos_x, ref pos_y);
            Visited(ref maze, pos_x, pos_y);
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 21; i++) // Prints out the final maze
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 21; j++)
            {
                Console.Write(maze[i, j]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried individually initiating all the subprograms, no errors occured.
However, after running the whole code, I was only able to print out the initial code, but not the final code with the route marked.

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

You need a little more logic adding into the navigation routine...

Try splitting the wall detection routine into two modes - WallAhead and WallToRight

At present you don't have wall collision on the MF method so it is important not to pass the turn/not turn logic until you know the space ahead is clear.

So logic becomes something like

```
if (!WallToRight(dir, pos_x, pos_y, maze)) {  // if there's a right turn available - take it
  TR(1, ref dir)
} else {
  while (WallAhead(dir, pos_x, pos_y, maze)) { // keep turning until the way ahead is clear
    TR(1,ref dir)
  }
}
MF(dir, ref pos_x, ref pos_y);
Visited(ref maze, pos_x, pos_y);
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suspect your algorithm is incorrect. The way to find this out would be to debug your code. Place a break point at "Prints out the final maze", do you ever reach it? Do you get any exceptions? Place a break point at the start of the navigate method and step thru the code, line by line, do you get what you are expecting? It is really easy to get index out of range exceptions for code like this if you are not careful.

I would also recommend some other changes

1. I would suggest using [Djikstras algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm), since that should give you the *shortest* path, while still being fairly simple to implement.
2. Don't use `char` for your nodes. Create an enum, like `enum NodeType{Wall, Free, Target}`
3. don't use `ref char[,]`. Arrays are a *reference type*, so even without `ref` you are only passing a reference, not a copy of the array. `ref` is only useful if you intend to replace the array, or possibly to spot code by inexperienced programmers that think it will make their code "go fast".
4. Create a method to print your maze, instead of repeating the code at multiple places.